# How To Unset The Array If Values Are Empty In PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to unset the array if the Array values are empty in the multidimensional array. Here's my Array:

```
Array
    (
        [main] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [title] => df
                        [link] => fdf
                    )
    
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [title] => 
                        [link] => 
                    )
    
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [title] => 
                        [link] => 
                    )
    
            )
    
    )
```

My PHP Code:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
  if(empty($value)){
      unset($menuDataJson[$key]);
  }
  
}
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: array_filter() .

Comment: You do realise that that code is not processing the inner arrays, but just the outer `main` array??

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you iterate over the root array, which has only one element 'main'. The following snippet should do the trick.

```
<?php

$array = [
    'main' => [
        [
            'title' => 'df',
            'link'  => 'fdf',
        ],
        [
            'title' => '',
            'link'  => '',
        ],
        [
            'title' => '',
            'link'  => '',
        ],
    ]
];


foreach ($array['main'] as $key => $value){
    if (empty($value['title'])){
        unset($array['main'][$key]);
    }
}

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: That's your array structure, not sure if you can avoid it.

Comment: if you don't want to pass, or cannot pass ['main'], you could use [this](https://3v4l.org/shWqV)

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```php
foreach ($array['main'] as $key => $value){
    if (empty($value['title']) && empty($value['link'])){
        unset($array['main'][$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The function `array_filter` will do that.

```
$result = array_filter($array);
```

**However**, if no callback function is specified, all empty entries of array will be removed, such as `""` (an empty string), `0` (0 as an integer), `0.0` (0 as a float), `"0"` (0 as a string), `NULL`, `FALSE` and `array()` or `[]` (an empty array).

if you have this case, so add a callback function.

```
function customFilter($var)
{
    return ($var !== NULL && $var !== FALSE && $var !== "");
}
```

and use them for the 2nd parameter.

```
$result = array_filter($array, 'customFilter');
```

If you have a multidimensional array, so is an enhancement necessary.

```
function array_filter_recursive($input, $callback = null)
{
    foreach ($input as &$value)
    {
        if (is_array($value))
        {
            $value = array_filter_recursive($value, $callback);
        }
    }
   
    return array_filter($input, $callback);
}
```

Use this function with your array like `array_filter_recursive($array)`.

Comment: check my answer with a little modification it is now working

Comment: This will only operate on the outer level of the array (where there's one key, `'main'`). Also, why reinvent the wheel when PHP has the `empty` function?